# Yii Framework yii_user + blog

Tags: php, frameworks, yii

I have seemed to successfully implement the yii user module within the finished version of the blog tutorial and now been stuck on an error where it is looking for the author_id to match an id within the tbl_user table, although with the yii user module you start using a new table tbl_users..so other users except the first one don't match and can't create posts.. this is the error that pops up.

```
Error 500
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint     violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails     (`yii`.`tbl_post`, CONSTRAINT `FK_post_author` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

So I can't find where it looks to match for an ID within the table 'tbl_user' ....

I've looked everywhere, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

This means that there is a key tbl_post.author_id that is not the same as tbl_user.id.

An example for you to better understand is that you try to insert an post with author_id = 5, but in the table tbl_user you only have let's say ids with values: 1, 2, 3, 7, 9 ... no 5 anyway.